# bind source path does not exist: /host_mnt

Tags: ddev

I have a ddev installation on macOS which I used for a while.

ddev 1.16.2

docker 20.10.0

macOS 11.0.1 - Intel

Today I upgraded to docker 20.10.0 and in the process to ddev 1.16.2.

When I start an existing site, that worked all the time I get

```
Creating ddev-mysite-db ... error
 
ERROR: for ddev-mysite-db  Cannot create container for service db: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /host_mnt/Users/me/Documents/Development/WebSite/mysite/.ddev
```

This started to happen after I upgraded docker from the previous version. Upgrading ddev did not change too much.

Even when I create a new site, the same error message pops up so I am pretty much stuck.

At least for me it looks like the docker 20.10.0 breaks ddev. Any ideas how to deal with that are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker/macOS are not allowing access to the directory ~/Documents.

Starting with macOS Catalina, ~/Documents is a "protected directory", so you have to allow docker access to it, and docker should prompt.

However, Docker Desktop for Mac's 3.0.0 release (which I imagine you're referring to) had a bug where it did not do this properly. I imagine you need to upgrade to version 3.0.1 which was released today. Just "Check for updates"

Answer (score 5):

In Docker > Preferences > Experimental features you can try disabling gRPC, and make Docker use osxfs file sharing system.

[image]

Reference: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4859#issuecomment-689012097